# Jackson simple data binding with JSON ... how is it helpful.. what am I missing?

Tags: java, json, jackson

When I saw that you could do simple data binding with Jackson, I instinctively felt like this would be very useful. The prospect of not having to design/create specific Java classes is very appealing. But I don't understand how simple data binding really speeds things up. If you end with a `Map<String, Object>` then there's a fair amount of hoops to jump through to get that data out of the map, no?

I must be missing something here because it seems to me that you end up with a different kind of parsing headache. Instead of manually parsing the JSON yourself or writing a class for full binding, you're pulling teeth with all sorts of casting, etc to get the correct data from the `Map`.

What am I missing? Can someone show me where simple data binding shines?

Answer (score 2):

Simple data binding may be useful in the situation where you don't know the specific structure of the JSON that you are parsing and you need to handle it programmatically (maybe the structure is even defined in configuration, maybe not).

While you could also use the Tree Model for this, simple data binding may be easier.

Though, if the JSON structure is known at compile-time, it makes sense to just use full data binding (Java classes).

Comment: At some point you're gonna have to know what that data is BEFORE run-time, no? Otherwise, how will you know to case some Object value as, say, a `HashMap<String, String>`

Comment: Not necessarily -- it is possible that names, for example, contains some structural information ("name.that.implies.path"). Or you may read structural definition from a file. Or structure is so varied that number of permutations is huge. As to how to find structure; you can use 'typeof' to figure out structure of a property -- however, for this style, Tree Model (JsonNode) is indeed more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

I am not going to argue that this is usually simpler (it isn't), so if you don't see the point, feel free to completely ignore this style. The reason Jackson offers multiple models (data-binding/untyped, tree model, streaming) is that they offer different kinds of trade-offs; and there is no need to use all of them if one works best for you.

But the main use case as I see it is for simplest of code, where all you do is extract one or two values. If so it may seem unnecessary to define a class. Another possibility are recursive data structures.

And the last reason I think is that many developers come from scripting languages (perl, javascript) where it is common to deal with "untyped" objects (in Perl, "hashes"). For them this may seem like the most natural approach, similar to how they used to do things.